# Access will not let me add a specific field into a combobox (although it allows other fields that I do not want)

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2016

I am very new to access, so I assume that I am just doing something terribly simple wrong, but I am totally lost.  I am making a form to sort data for a hospital that I am interning at, and while everything so far has been a breeze, when trying to make a combobox in a data entry form, I am unable to add the data I want into combobox (Procedure and Physician), although I can add the ID for whatever reason.  I have posted screen shots of my query and of what happens when I try to add in the combobox, and I am more than willing to add additional information if need be.

Also, don't worry, I checked with my supervisor and she said that posting this online did not break HIPPA or any other legal rules as there is no patient information in the database (yet).

[image: Query for physician comboboxes]

[image: Query for procedure combobox]

[image: I select the correct query]

[image: All items besides the ID are missing]

The same thing also happened in both of my physician comboboxes.

Comment: Also, MUCH less important, when you make an unwanted record and then delete it, the ID number's of all records skip that number (eg if you delete record three and then make another record, it will be record 4 event though there are only 3 records total).  Does anyone no how to stop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the ProcedureName field a Memo field?  If so try changing the query to select it using CStr:

```
SELECT CStr(Procedures.ProcedureName) AS ProcedureName
```

Check if there are any Memo fields in your Physician table as well and try a similar approach.

Comment: As I said I am very new, and I am not sure how to find out if it is a memo field. I am checking the design view and datasheet view but I don't see it...

Comment: I figured it out :D    FYI memo fields have been renamed long text fields.